# Team Collaboration via PHP Code Comments

Tags: php, comments, collaboration

Are there any tools or ways or practices in which multiple programmers on a single project collaborate using comments in the code. For example, when a senior programmer reviews the code and comments some TODOs in the code. And the programmer (or all the team) gets a notification via Email about that TODO. This may be possible by a simple script parsing through all files and checking for differences in files; may be I can code such a program on my server. But do anyone know such a tool exists?

Comment: This is a really cool idea, unfortunately I don't know any tool that already does this. But it should be easy by using a PHP script that loops through every script checking all TODO once a day (or something like that) and sending an email to employees. Still, really cool idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you guys to work with a decent IDE like PhpStorm that keeps those TODO's for you and knows to index them into one search,
Then, I would strongly recommend to work with git, this is the best way to develop as a team,
git will help you versionaize your code in a very easy way.

Good luck.